# Differences between LUKS and Veracrypt

Tags: encryption, pbkdf2, luks, veracrypt, kdf

These two FDE solutions are similar, but I noticed different executions speed: specially mounting a device it seems that Veracrypt takes more time decrypting it. 
So I would like to compare it with LUKS analizing the header format.

I know about LUKS that there is a 2 level key hierarchy and 8 keyslot, maybe Veracrypt is similar.

My question is: how Veracrypt's header is designed?

Answer (score 2):

Both of them will have varying times depending on iteration count:

[LUKS](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) hides this somewhat in most Linux distro installs, though it can be changed afterwards, per [this Stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101343/100202)

[Veracrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Header%20Key%20Derivation) makes setting the count trivial - use and change the "PIM" setting.